# IdentityServer3 bearertoken ignored? if not localhost

Tags: identityserver3

For the past couple of years we've been developing a client/server application and it's been working well with us hosting the server and applications. I've recently started work on getting our mobile app to connect and have run into a snag.

The mobile app can login and obtain a token but when it presents that token for an API call Owin is failing to create a valid Principal.

The same API call from our desktop app (running on the same physical machine as the server) has an HttpRequestMessage "MS_OwinContext" property with the Authentication.User field populated. The same call from the mobile does not.

Yet both of them seem to be sending the same API request (different bearer token of course). Alternative can anyone tell me where I might at least start looking or how I could get information from OWIN as to what it's doing? It's also worth pointing out that the mobile app (Xamarin) shares most of its code with the desktop application.

Right now I'm staring at a black box and all I know is that 'it doesn't work'.

Comment: Okay so I've finally got OWIN logging working and the problem is that I'm getting a SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException. As I sort of suspected it doesn't seem to like the fact my mobile device is connecting via the host name instead of localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Okay the problem was that the server was setting Authority in the bearer options to be localhost. Audience is derived from this so when connecting using the host name validation fails.

The answer appears to therefore not use localhost as part of the authority.